# Entity Framework: adding an entity to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext as DbSet in an Azure functions app

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, dbcontext

Just starting out with Azure Functions and EF.

I have the following code:

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Badge> Badge { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new BadgeDataConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserDataConfiguration());
    }
}
```

**BadgeDataConfiguration.cs**

```
public class BadgeDataConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Badge>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Badge> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.id)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(x => x.userid)
            .HasColumnName("userid")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.description)
            .HasColumnName("description")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.category)
            .HasColumnName("category")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.picture)
            .HasColumnName("picture")
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

**UserDataConfiguration.cs**

```
public class UserDataConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.id)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(x => x.username)
            .HasColumnName("userid")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.firstname)
            .HasColumnName("description")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.lastname)
            .HasColumnName("category")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.password_hash)
            .HasColumnName("picture")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.email)
            .HasColumnName("category")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.picture)
            .HasColumnName("category")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(x => x.date_created)
            .HasColumnName("category")
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

I initially created the `Badge` entity and got everything working within an Azure function.

For example with:

```
dbContext.Badge.ToList();
```

However once I added all the code for the user entity I always get the following exception when executing `dbContext.User.ToList();`

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: GetUser. Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Invalid object name 'User'

The `Badge` entity still functions normally.

What am I missing here?

Versions:

- .NET 6.0
- Azure Functions v4
- Entity Framework Core v6.0.0

Comment: Did you create the `User` table? That's a SQL Server error complaining there's no table with that name

Comment: I created the table with with the name "users" instead of "user". Changing to a table "user" got it workling. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database table was named wrong.
Changing it from "users" to "user" got everything working.